# How can I send an image (form-data file) with wp_remote_post?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have `curl`, which works:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$cfile = new CURLFile($_FILES['form_name']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['form_name']['type'], $_FILES['form_name']['name']);
$new_image = ["image" => $cfile];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $new_image);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

But when I trying to send form-data with `wp_remote_post` like:

```
$result = wp_remote_post($url, [
                        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'],
                        'body' => $new_image
                    ]);
```

I have `400 error` in answer, and error in `[body]`:

```
[body] => {"status":"error","msg":"$_FILES[\u0027image\u0027] not found"}
```

How can I correctly sending an image with `wp_remote_post`?

Comment: you want to pass file name with your request right?

Comment: I need to pass a file in multipart/form-data format)